# Await after creating WinForm UI Control within a new Task causes deadlock?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have this weird behavior in a WinForms app. I call this task from Form_Shown event handler of my main form.

```
Task.Run(() => WatchHistory(CancellationTokenSource.Token));
```

Function definition is as follows. FinishedRequestItem object is a WinForms UI Control. It dead locks at await Task.Delay. I noted that a new Sync Context was created as soon as FinishedRequestItem object was created.This context is different from that of the main form UI.

```
    private async void WatchHistory(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var completedRequests = await processContext.ProcessRequests.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (completedRequests.Any())
            {
                FinishedRequestItem entry = Program.Container.GetInstance<FinishedRequestItem>();

            }

            await Task.Delay(CurrentHistoryRefreshMilliseconds, cancellationToken);
        }

    }
```

However if I create the UI Control using Invoke method as shown below it doesn't dead lock. I am curious why? Since the task is not running in UI context, what prevents Task.Delay from resuming in above code?

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var completedRequests = await processContext.ProcessRequests.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (completedRequests.Any())
            {

                FinishedRequestItem entry = null;

                this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
                {
                    entry = Program.Container.GetInstance<FinishedRequestItem>();
                });

            }

            await Task.Delay(CurrentHistoryRefreshMilliseconds, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: You should only be creating UI controls on the UI thread. You also shouldn't be `async void`, instead use `async Task`.

Comment: I am using async Task in my updated code, I am aware its a better pattern. However the problem still exists. I think it has to do with Task.Delay trying to resume in the same thread which is waiting for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` in every place you don't want `await` to resume on the current synchronization context. If you did so for your `Task.Delay` call, you would not have that issue (but most probably a different one).

> However if I create the UI Control using Invoke method as shown below it doesn't dead lock. I am curious why? Since the task is not running in UI context, what prevents Task.Delay from resuming in above code?

In fact the way you use it, `Task.Delay` will try to resume at the whatever the **current** synchronization context is when you invoke it. And here is the point. Normally the thread pool threads do not have a synchronization context (or use the default one which effective does not do any synchronization). But every `System.Windows.Forms.Control` by default installs (sets `SynchronizationContext.Current` to) a [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) in it's constructor. Hence after the call

```
Program.Container.GetInstance<FinishedRequestItem>()
```

the current synchronization context is changed, and then `Task.Delay` tries to resume on that context, but of course it can't because there is no message pump running on that thread (which is required for `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` to function properly).

In general you should not create UI elements on non UI threads.